# Using SharpAESCrypt to encrypt strings

Tags: c#, aes

I decided to use the SharpAESCrypt implementation of AES encryption in C#. According to their documentation (https://www.aescrypt.com/sharp_aes_crypt.html) you should be able to use a static method, providing a password string, plain-text input stream and a output stream. The data I get out of my output stream appears to be all zero's.

I suspect I am doing something wrong converting strings to a stream and back. Can anyone see anything that is obviously wrong with the code below? (It compiles and runs, but the newByteArray is filled with 0's at the end)

```
    private void encryptMemStream()
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DecryptedTB.Text);
        using (MemoryStream plainText = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            using (MemoryStream encryptedData = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //plainText.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                SharpAESCrypt.Encrypt(PasswordTB.Text, plainText, encryptedData);
                encryptedData.Position = 0;
                byte[] newByteArray = new byte[encryptedData.Length];
                newByteArray = encryptedData.ToArray();
                EncryptedTB.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newByteArray);
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: The native implementation of this code uses fileStreams, but it should work with MemoryStreams too. I will test filestreams and add my results here.

More Edits:

So when you use a file stream you call this code

```
    //Code from the AES Crypt Library
    public static void Encrypt(string password, string inputfile, string outputfile)
    {
        using (FileStream infs = File.OpenRead(inputfile))
        using (FileStream outfs = File.Create(outputfile))
            Encrypt(password, infs, outfs);
    }
```

Which calls a function which I have been calling directly

```
    //Code from the AES Crypt Library
    public static void Encrypt(string password, Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        int a;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
        SharpAESCrypt c = new SharpAESCrypt(password, output, OperationMode.Encrypt);
        while ((a = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            c.Write(buffer, 0, a);
        c.FlushFinalBlock();
    }
```

There is obviously some subtle difference in using a MemoryStream and a FileStream which I don't understand. FileStream works fine, where as MemoryStream returns a blank array...

Comment: you should use using when you use streams

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: i would avoid using ascii.

Comment: I will try other encoding types.

Comment: That didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Having just downloaded the source for AESCrypt and tried to run your code in linqpad it seems to work to me. It outputs what seems to be a constant headerblock which includes a lot of 0 bytes then on byte 172 it seems to start up with non 0 bytes which I assume is the encrypted payload. I get a similar pattern when using the file one as I do with your code. Perhaps you could confirm how long your byte array is and where the zeroes start and end.

Comment: Also as a note `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newByteArray)` is likely to get you garbage since the byte array is not likely to be a valid UTF8 byte array. If you need the byte array to be printable use `Convert.ToBase64String`

Comment: I changed to Base64Strings for the output, which actually gave me some data, but there are sill a lot of 0 cells. If I try and decrypt the 'encryptedData stream' it either spits out garbage or throws a header exception error, which suggests that how ever I am encoding the text into the stream isn't consistent.
@Chris, have you managed to use it to take data from a text box, encrypt it, then decrypt it and display it?

Comment: I just took my inputs from strings. http://pastebin.com/K9yt1pEa is the exact code that I ran in linqpad (https://www.linqpad.net/). AS you can see I've just copy and pasted the AESCrypt code into that. This successfully round trips the text. I've realised I made a few changes to yours in that I didn't explicitly set the stream position to 0 and I didn't allocate a new byte array to the `newByteArray` variable (which is unnecessary since you replace it in the next line anyway). I should embphasize that there were a lot of zeros in mine anyway. I assume they are header padding.

Comment: The byteArray.Select(...).Dump(); is throwing an error. 

'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Dump'

Comment: @Chris -  Ok, I didn't realise that Dump was a Linqpad feature. No matter how I write the final byte array out to a text box though, there seems to be no header information.

Comment: (Hopefully) Final update - I think the error was coming from trying to put the encrypted data out to a string. I am now saving it as .bin file and it is working fine including decryption. The reason I didn't want to use the native implementation of just using files both ends is because I don't want the decrypted data being written to a hard drive.
@Chris if you want to put your answer as a solution I'll accept it :D Thank you very much.

Comment: Ah. The output bytes are binary data which is why I mentioned earlier you shouldn't use UTF8 and instead base64 encode it if you need it to be a printable string. If you use base64 encoding/decoding to go to/from a printable string then hopefully you'll be good.

Comment: Done. I think my answer contains everything of use I put here in comments so I'll probably delete all these comments to keep things neater. Before I do though let me know if you think there is anything here I should put in my answer and haven't. :)

Comment: I put the full working code at the bottom of you answer just for completeness. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: @Mike159: I notice you've got `newByteArray.Select(x => x.ToString("x"));` in the code you added. You are aware that this doesn't do anything aren't you? I assume its there because I had it with the `.Dump()` in my test code I pasted and you just removed the Dump to get it working. I've edited it out of the answer but thought I'd remind you to remove it from your code. In case you didn't know it converts the  byte array to strings with the hex value of the bytes. Useful for examining the binary contents. Also don't forget to change ASCII back to UTF8 if needed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick code review reveals a few things including what, from discussion, seems to be the main problem you are facing. The problematic line is

```
EncryptedTB.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newByteArray);
```

This line is taking the binary data in newByteArray and telling your code that it is a valid UTF8 byte array. Chances are that it is almost certainly not actually going to be valid UTF8. Parts of it may be (such as the header) but the actually encrypted data is not going to be and so you shouldn't use this method to get a string.

If you need a printable string to put in a textbox of some sort then the correct way to do this for binary data is through base64 encoding.

```
EncryptedTB.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(newByteArray);
```

Base64 encoding effectively takes groups of three bytes (24 bits) and converts them to groups of four characters.

A further note while I'm here is that in these two lines:

```
byte[] newByteArray = new byte[encryptedData.Length];
newByteArray = encryptedData.ToArray();
```

You declare a byte array and allocate a new array to it. You then immediately discard this in favour of the array from `encryptedData.ToArray()`. This does not put data into the array allocated by `new byte[encryptedData.Length]` but creates a new array and puts it into the `newByteArray` variable. Better would be to just do:

```
byte[] newByteArray = encryptedData.ToArray();
```

Full working code below:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceText);
Byte[] newByteArray;
using (MemoryStream plainText = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    using (MemoryStream encryptedData = new MemoryStream())
    {
        SharpAESCrypt.Encrypt(password, plainText, encryptedData);
        newByteArray = encryptedData.ToArray();
    }
}
EncryptedTB.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(newByteArray);
```

Comment: Can anyone please tell me how to decrypt the string back to normal text?
I'm getting error like `Invalid header marker`

Comment: I've used the same code you've suggested for encryption and it working fine. For the decryption I've only changed `SharpAESCrypt.Encrypt` to `SharpAESCrypt.Decrypt`. While executing that line, the error is coming

Comment: @RealSteel: If your problem is different to the one in this question then you should open a new question. In it try to have sufficient code to reproduce the problem - that is show your encryption method, and decryption method and sample calls to each of them (presumably passing the output of the encryption into the decryption method). The error sounds like you are passing something incorrect to your decryption method and it kind of needs full code to diagnose something like that...