# SharpAESCrypt Encrypting and Decrypting strings

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I've a requirement where I need to implement `cross platform encryption and decryption`.
So, I've done some googling and found this link

- https://www.aescrypt.com

So,I've planned to use `SharpAESCrypt` and using the latest version `1.3.1` of it.

Now, my problem is : I'm able to encrypt the string by converting into a stream but unable to decrypt it back using the same password.

I've found some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406439/using-sharpaescrypt-to-encrypt-strings/31427640#31427640) and have implemented the same.

My Sample Code:

**Encryption**

```
protected void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtInput.Text.Trim());
            Byte[] newByteArray;
            using (MemoryStream plainText = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            {
                using (MemoryStream encryptedData = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    SharpAESCrypt.SharpAESCrypt.Encrypt("ABCD@123", plainText, encryptedData);
                    newByteArray = encryptedData.ToArray();
                }
            }
            string FinalText = Convert.ToBase64String(newByteArray);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

**Decryption**

```
protected void btnDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtOutput.Text.Trim());
            Byte[] newByteArray;

            string output = "";
            using (MemoryStream plainText = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            {
                using (MemoryStream encryptedData = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    SharpAESCrypt.SharpAESCrypt.Decrypt("ABCD@123", plainText, encryptedData);
                    newByteArray = encryptedData.ToArray();
                }
            }
            //string FinalText = Convert.ToBase64String(newByteArray);
            string FinalText = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error like `Invalid header marker`. can anyone please let me know the mistake I'm doing?

**Note: Needed some suggestions for the best cross platform(iOS, Android and C#) encryption and decryption library available.**

Comment: For a good cross platform solution see [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor). It includes password extension, random iv and encryption authentication, in short what is needed to obtain secure encryption.

Comment: may I know the reason, why I've got a downvote for the question. If I can know the proper reason, I won't be repeating it next time!

Comment: It wasn't me so I can only guess: there is no test data, input or output. SharpAESCrypt looks good but is missing some details such as how the password is transformed to the key encrypting key used to encrypt the the data encryption key. I have doubts that it is performant on OSX and especially on iOS, I have seen implementations that are 200 and 1000 times (respectively) slower than vendor supplied Common Crypto, you might benchmark the implementation. RNCryptor is also nonperformance on some platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Decrypt method, you need to reconstitute the encrypted byte array using Convert.FromBase64String instead of Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes. The last part where you are reconstituting the decrypted string using UTF8 is correct.